# What does “a relation is least” mean?

Tags: ecmascript-next, ecma262

In the [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-and-relation-specification-type), it says:

> A Relation is least with respect to some conditions when it is the smallest Relation that satisfies those conditions.

To be honest, I do not really understand the meaning of this sentence. Can you provide examples when a relation is smaller than another relation, and explain why?

Comment: Please give some context for that sentence. The spec text is long. Maybe you can even link the relevant section?

Comment: Ah, you're reading the latest draft not ES6.

Comment: "Smaller" probably refers to the size of the relation, i.e. the number of its elements.

Comment: Here’s an example of this definition being used: _“For a candidate execution `execution`, `execution.[[ReadsFrom]]` is the **least Relation** on events that satisfies the following. […]”_ — [27.6.3 Relations of Candidate Executions — `reads-from`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-reads-from). Sections 27.6.5 and 27.6.6 use it, too.

Comment: `{}` is smaller than `{(0,0)}` because `{}` has 0 elements and `{(0,0)}` has one element.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for editing my question and corresponding links. It's interesting enough. But so far it’s not clear enough. And I think this is not about the number of elements.

Comment: Btw, if you are [cross-posting your questions](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1711), please mention it somewhere.

Comment: @bergi haha, found me oops. Well, is it really bad to ask the same question in a few places? There, if they give an answer, then most likely more correct than on SO. And what exactly do you want me to point out?

Comment: @MaximPro No, it's not necessarily a bad thing (and no longer [as harshly criticised as in the old days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting)), the bad thing is to not mention it in your post so that readers cannot know you already got a response elsewhere.